# why protobuf prefer code-generator other than dynamic loading at runtime

Tags: protocol-buffers, config, code-generation, auto-generate

Protobuf prefer ***compiling xxx.proto to source code*** (like protoc)

other than a liberary just ***loading xxx.proto at runtime*** (like DynamicMessage, protobuf-dynamic)

Why more projects prefer this way?

### some compares:

- compute: compile **vs** runtime
- reload:  recompile-proto + recompile-program + restart  **vs** reload config
- check syntax: compile **vs** any time
- client update: rebuild-client + download **vs** download-proto + reload

Answer (score 1):

Many programming languages are not scripting languages, C++ for instance. For those type of languages it is preferred and often required to know what you are dealing with at compile time. This instead of generating the message class format at run time. If you do that you need a lot of type checking and availability checking to have the code working properly and consistent. In theory you could supply a different proto file in which case the code should not crash.